# Does SQLiteDatabase.query() run on seprate thread or should I call it from an AsyncTask

Tags: android

I am querying by calling [SQLiteDatabase.query()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) the database and I am wondering if I should do it in another thread other than the main thread or if it already does that.

Comment: Its run on UI thread itself..if you want you can run it in other thread..

Comment: It runs on the thread it is called from. The recommendation is to run queries on a background thread but there is nothing enforcing that.